# Mysqli bind_param error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a issue with my prepared statement, I have searched through stack for the answer and tried many off them them to no avail, I have check the insert statement which is correct, I have also tried using the statement as a regular statement which seems to work, 
The error I get is as below

```
Fatal error:call to function bind_param()on a non object in ** on line 23
```

When I use a normal query on the first query the second does not show the error

The code is

```
public function reg_user($name,$username,$password,$email){
        $password = password_hash($password);
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uname= ? OR uemail = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username,$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count_row = $stmt->num_rows; 
        if($count_row == 0){
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (uname,upass,fullname,uemail) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username,$password,$name,$email); //line 23 
            $return = $stmt->execute();
            return $return;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot bind multiple parameters at the same time. You should pass them as an array in `execute()`, or bind one parameter each time. The former is more modular and less redundant

Comment: The error can't be on line 23 - the code only has 15 lines!

Comment: Yes but it's part off a class which has more lines, it's pointless posting the full class when this is the function which has the error

Comment: I wonder if anyone here is interested in the *real* explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines of code after the first `$stmt->execute`

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$count_row = $result->num_rows;
```

The reason why your code fails is because you are trying to get the number of rows from a Prepared Statement object instead of a Result

Comment: Forgot to change that back to prepare after the trying a standard query, updates question to add back in prepare, this also still gives me the same issue

Comment: So the error is caused by the second call to bind_param?

Comment: Line 23 is the second bind which gives the error but works using a standard query one the first bind, which is what is confusing me

Comment: After the first $stmt->execute try adding this code:

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$count_row = $result->num_rows;

Let me now if that worked so that I can edit the answer

Comment: That worked! Edit your answers and I will mark as the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: You you are going to say that [this method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) doesn't work?